# Disabling johnny-cache in admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-cache, django-johnny-cache

I am using johnny-cache. Is there an easy way to disable it from Admin, but let it work transparently everywhere else?

I have looked in the johhny cache docs - http://pythonhosted.org/johnny-cache/, but can't seem to find this.

Comment: You might have some luck with the `MAN_IN_BLACKLIST` option: http://pythonhosted.org/johnny-cache/queryset_cache.html#settings